# Agrupar filas realizando Operaciones

Tags: sql, oracle

Tengo una duda que puede parecer un poco tonta, pero llevo varios días dándole vueltas y no consigo encontrarle solución, estoy trabajando con Oracle y tengo estos datos

```
floor((rownum + 1) /2) as parejas | HORA
------------------------
1 | 09:00 
1 | 07:00 
2 | 03:00 
2 | 01:30
```

Y me gustaría obtener un resultado que tome las parejas y reste la hora, devolviendo como resultado

```
floor((rownum + 1) /2) as parejas| HORA
------------------------
1 | 02:00
2 | 01:30
```

¿Se os ocurre alguna forma?

Muchas gracias, un saludo

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de datos es `hora`?

Comment: Es de tipo time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dado que la columna `hora` es de tipo `time`, puedes realizar aritmética de fechas directamente sobre la columna para obtener la diferencia de tiempo entre una y otra, por ejemplo:

```
select floor((rownum + 1) /2) as parejas, max(hora) - min(hora) as hora
  from TuTabla
 group by floor((rownum + 1) /2)
```

Esto tomará la hora mayor de cada *pareja* y le restará la hora menor.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias, conforme me has comentado arriba, me funciona correctamente!